# Unable to find an entry point named '' in DLL 'cvextern'

Tags: c#, opencv, dll, emgucv

I am currently trying to get the CUDA part of EMGU CV working. After the compilation, when I try to run it, I get the error "Unable to find an entry point named 'cudaCreateLinearFilter' in DLL 'cvextern'. Where cudaCreateLinearFilter can be arbitrarily replaced by any CUDA-related function within EMGU CV. EMGU CV itself works fine tough.

I tried the fix described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257502/Creating-Your-First-EMGU-Image-Processing-Project) and copied all the mentioned dlls(like cudart64_32_16.dll and opencv_calib3d220.dll) into the Debug folder within the project. Unfortunately this did not work either.

I also replaced all the EMGU dlls already once with a newly downloaded version.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Source = https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv/issues/728

When you target .Net Framework, you will have to set the build architecture to either “x86” or “x64”.  [...] When the build architecture is set to “AnyCpu” (the default), native binary from nuget packages will not be copied over [the proper folder].

Answer (score -1):

You need the cvextern.dll file. On my machine it is in emgucv-windesktop_x64-cuda-tbb-ipp-icc 3.1.0.2283\bin\x64

Since you have verified the easy solution let's dive a bit deeper. cvextern contains the entry points into the OpenCv DLLs. If one digs a bit you will find that cudaCreateLinearFilter is contained in opencv_filters310.dll in the bin\x64 folder. If you have included this DLL in your debug or release folder I think you should be OK.

Hope this helps!

Doug

Comment: I already have this one. Otherwise I assume the error should sound something similiar like "unable to load cvextern"

Comment: It's not that issue.